# How to hide part of a string in a recyclerview?

Tags: java, android, string, arraylist, textview

I have a recyclerview where I am displaying a string which contains a id,name and contact number as a single string.I would like to hide the id in the string.I am using the following code to add the string to the array list.I am displaying the concatenated string in a textview like (1-XYZ 0123456789)

```
   private void showGuestDetails(String response) {
        Guest_info guest_info = new Guest_info(response);
        guest_info.ParseGuestInfo();

        String guestid[] = guest_info.guest_id;

        for (int i = 0; i < guestid.length; i++) {
            list.add(guest_info.guest_id[i] + "-" + guest_info.guest_name[i] + "  " + guest_info.guest_mobile[i]);

        }
    }
```

This is the adapter class that I am using:-

```
public class GuestAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<GuestAdapter.GuestViewHolder> {

    private List<String> list_item ;
    public Context mcontext;
    private BookingActivity bookingActivity;


    public GuestAdapter(List<String> list, Context context, BookingActivity bookingActivity) {

        list_item = list;
        mcontext = context;
        this.bookingActivity =bookingActivity;
    }

    // Called when RecyclerView needs a new RecyclerView.ViewHolder of the given type to represent an item.
    @Override
    public GuestAdapter.GuestViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                                         int viewType) {
        // create a layout
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(
                R.layout.list_item, null);

        GuestViewHolder myViewHolder = new GuestViewHolder(view);
        return myViewHolder;
    }

    // Called by RecyclerView to display the data at the specified position.
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final GuestViewHolder viewHolder, final int position ) {


        viewHolder.guest_name.setText(list_item.get(position));

        viewHolder.guest_name.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {



              bookingActivity.setGuestText(list_item.get(position));


            }
        });

    }

    //Returns the total number of items in the data set hold by the adapter.
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return list_item.size();
    }


    // initializes textview in this class
    public static class GuestViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public TextView guest_name;

        public GuestViewHolder(View itemLayoutView) {
            super(itemLayoutView);

            guest_name = (TextView) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.guestName);

        }
    }
}
```

> Is there a way by which I will be able to display everything after the
>   hyphen and hide everything before the hyphen including the hyphen. Any
>   help or suggestion is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: split the string while displaying it.

Comment: can you provide an example of your string, so I can provide you sample code.

Comment: @VishalSanghani please check my updated question thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this

```
String[] separated = list.get(position).split("-");
separated[0]; // this will contain your ID eg 1
separated[1]; // this will contain your remaining string eg XYZ 0123456789

viewHolder.guest_name.setText(separated[1]);
```

Comment: The problem is I want to hide part of the textview how will I achieve that?

Comment: you need to only display separated[1];

Comment: this will not have id in it

Comment: But I am using the id later so I need the id.I just don't want to display it.I have also updated my question with the adapter class.

Comment: just put the above code in your onBindViewHolder and you will only display remaining part of string and your arraylist will remain as it is.

Answer (score 6):

your going good, but at the place of String List, just pass complete Object List of (Guest_info class),
and update your adapter like this

```
public class GuestAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<GuestAdapter.GuestViewHolder> {

//private List<String> list_item ;
private List<Guest_info> list_item ;
public Context mcontext;
private BookingActivity bookingActivity;


public GuestAdapter(List<Guest_info> list, Context context, BookingActivity bookingActivity) {

    list_item = list;
    mcontext = context;
    this.bookingActivity =bookingActivity;
}

// Called when RecyclerView needs a new RecyclerView.ViewHolder of the given type to represent an item.
@Override
public GuestAdapter.GuestViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                                     int viewType) {
    // create a layout
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(
            R.layout.list_item, null);

    GuestViewHolder myViewHolder = new GuestViewHolder(view);
    return myViewHolder;
}

// Called by RecyclerView to display the data at the specified position.
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final GuestViewHolder viewHolder, final int position ) {

    Guest_info bean = list_item.get(position);
    viewHolder.guest_name.setText(bean.getGuest_name());

    viewHolder.guest_name.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
          bookingActivity.setGuestText(bean.getGuest_name());
        }
    });

}

//Returns the total number of items in the data set hold by the adapter.
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return list_item.size();
}


// initializes textview in this class
public static class GuestViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public TextView guest_name;

    public GuestViewHolder(View itemLayoutView) {
        super(itemLayoutView);
        guest_name = (TextView) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.guestName);
    }
}
}
```

By this you can show data what ever you want, you don't need to do manipulation on string and can get complete data.

Answer (score 2):

yes you can pass Guest_info ArrayList in Adapter at the place of String ArrayList

Answer (score 1):

Split your string like that[we don't need third part so i will not store in a string]

```
String[] parts = list.get(position).split("-");
String first = parts[0];
String second = parts[1];
```

and use like that

```
viewHolder.guest_name.setText(parts[0]+"-"+parts[1]);
```